# Search on date string in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have date field, which is stored with following mapping:

```
"RecordedDate": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "DateAndNumber"
               }
```

Here is analyzer:

```
 "DateAndNumber": {
                     "pattern": "([/\\-]+)",
                     "type": "pattern"
                  }
```

When I'm searching with following query:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "RecordedDate", 
      "query": "RecordedDate:2\\/2\\/1902",
      "default_operator": "and"
}
```

I've got a lot of irrelevant search results which contains `2` and `1902` terms. E.g: `2/18/1902`, `5/2/1902` instead of `2/2/1902`.

Is there any way to make the analyzer take term position/offset into account as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `auto_generate_phrase_queries` to true in the query you suggestef. You can find more details in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). If that doesn't work for you, you could also use a phrase query directly - a [phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase) does exactly what you're asking for.

If you only have dates in your `DateAndNumber` field, using a [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) type for the field might be the best option though.

Comment: I received  `query malformed, no field after start_object` with `auto_generate_phrase_queries` set to true. Also, phrase query is not the solution, somebody could search, only part of date `5/1902`.

Comment: the `query malformed` is not related to the auto_generate clause being added: you probably forgot the outermost `query` field. as of the issue with part of the query - that will always be the case if you use a normal match query to match dates this way

Comment: Just put that property in wrong place, sorry. Alas that didn't help. For the match query - I also can't use it, this is case for one field, I've got a lot of ones, and I hope to fix it with analyzer/tokenizer/data type.

Comment: Just to get rid of misleading information, `auto_generate_phrase_queries` helped. It works as expected, there was some problems with analyzer.